# Classification erosion - semi-automatic classification plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, classification, image, erosion

I get an error when working *Classification Erosion* tool in *Semi-automatic Classification Plugin (SCP)*. I use QGIS v3.2.2 and SCP v6.2.4.

The tool is not changing the pixels of the raster layer and creates this short report:

```
**An error has occurred while executing Python code:**
*NameError: name 'd' is not defined 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sergio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\erosionTab.py", line 65, in erosionClassificationAction
    self.erosionClassification()
  File "C:/Users/Sergio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\erosionTab.py", line 81, in erosionClassification
    sN = cfg.osSCP.path.basename(str(d))
NameError: name 'd' is not defined*
```

Classification before erosion:

[image: Classification before erosion]

Comment: What isn't working about it specifically?

Comment: Please see the text of the question now with additional comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this plugin is  maintained by a specific person/team, this problem should be dealt by them and is outside the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `d` doesn't exist and `sN` is not used anywhere within the file. So, changing that line into comment avoid you to get that error.

I'm not sure if it works but try these:

1. Open `erosionTab.py` file in any editor. 
   (`C:/Users/Sergio/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\erosionTab.py`)
2. Go to line 81 (`sN=cfg.osSCP.path.basename(str(d))`)
3. Change to comment by adding hash `#` to beginning of the line. (`#sN=cfg.osSCP.path.basename(str(d))`)
4. Save the file, re-open QGIS and try to run SCP again.

Comment: Reported as a bug on GitHub